# oracle web logic in windows 10

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic12c

I try to install weblogic and also i download files but i dont know how to install weblogic fro these files for windows 10 64 bit .. i download these 3 files

1)fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls_quick

2)fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls

3)fmw_12.2.1.0.0_infrastructure

All 3 are executable jar file .. but i don't understand which file is for web logic?

i download from this website .. first option

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/wls-main-097127.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what are you looking for.
From [Official Oracle Middleware Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/index.html):

**The *Quick* Installer** offers full Java EE 7 development, and includes Oracle WebLogic Server and Oracle Coherence.

**The *generic* installer** also includes Oracle WebLogic Server and Oracle Coherence and adds examples and console help files.

**The Fusion Middleware *Infrastructure* installer** adds Fusion Middleware Control and Java Required Files (JRF) for managing Multitenant domains with multiple partitions. (Note: Licensed customers should obtain their Oracle WebLogic Server 12cR2 software here.)

Comment: i am looking for oracle forms and reports software.. i already have database 11g and 12c is also database so what if i install both database is there nay problem occur?